# Traducción: "Respuesta" en vez de "Responder" (Cola de revisión)

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

En la **cola de revisión**, al ver una respuesta:

[image: Ejemplo de respuesta en cola de revisión]

**Dice** `Responder`

**Debería decir** `Respuesta`

---

<sup>-La verdad que no es sólo un detalle para mí. No sé por qué, pero particularmente me molesta bastante verla escrita así</sup>

Comment: buff... ahora ya no puedo dejar de verlo..

Comment: Esta es tu última oportunidad. Después de esto, no hay vuelta atrás. Toma la píldora azul: el cuento termina, despiertas en tu cama y creerás lo que quieras creer. Toma la píldora roja: permaneces en el país de las maravillas y te mostraré qué tan profundo llega el agujero del conejo. Recuerda, todo lo que estoy ofreciendo es la verdad, nada más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corregido.

Gracias por avisar sobre este error. :)

Comment: Gracias Juan!!!